# What would be a good design to avoid methods with large number of parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am having a bit of a design issue.  What I am working on is a drag and drop in a C# desktop app.  I am using the .NET treeview control and a third party grid (not important).  I am using this drag and drop operation of a file system in more than one place so I've created a static class to handle this.  Now this is not just an ordinary file system.  The treeview is a representation of the directories and the grid has the files.  The complicated part is that there is a logical file system as well so all of this is stored in a database as well.  I am only explaining all of this because I wanted to explain why I have a problem.  Because I am working with a number of objects at this point, all of my static methods have a large number of parameters.  All of my static methods are pretty much all using the same parameters as wel  Would there be something I can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reduce your parameters by encapsulating those fields in common objects, e.g.

Instead of having:

```
void DoSomething(string first, string middle, string last);
```

You could have:

```
void DoSomething(Name name);
```

Where Name *could* be represented by,

```
public class Name
{
   string First {get; set;}
   string Middle {get; set;}
   string Last {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once we get to a certain number of method parameters (3-5), we create a class to hold the parameter arguments and then just pass an instance of this class as the argument.

This is especially useful if you have multiple methods with essentially the same arguments.

Don't get too carried away with this, though: if you have a parameter that is only used in one method, I wouldn't include this in the arguments class, just pass it as an extra parameter to the exception method.

Also, as a side benefit, this makes passing parameters to threads/background workers much easier because you already have the parameters in a class object.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are identifying a known "bad smell" labelled `long parameter list`. It is described very well [on this site](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/long-parameter-list).

I find the most straightforward solution is [introduce parameter object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object).

The other refactoring steps mentioned are:

- [replace parameter with method](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-parameter-with-method)
- [preserve whole object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/preserve-whole-object)

The potential problems with these two steps are that it introduces more coupling. It would require your static utility methods to know about these methods or existing objects, and this might be entirely inappropriate depending upon your design.